# Scala shell rendering very slowly in Windows 10 command prompt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, windows-10

I have my Apache Spark running on my Windows 10 machine. In that I use Command prompt to interact with the Spark-shell.

Spark-shell(Yarn mode) started normally. But while I execute any command in the shell, it prints the command very slowly like character by character.

Due to this issue it delays the command execution.

Note: Its working fine in other versions of Windows except windows 10.

Is there any issue with the jline or with cmd.exe?

It's very strange to find out the root cause. Can anyone give some peek about this if you have faced this issue? Please guide me to get it resolved.

Comment: Could provide some additional details such as how many executors you use, memory per executor, cores in your machine, size of the data, what kind of job you run (together with code maybe)?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis, I hope its not related to configuration or code. The same package runs properly in different Windows OS apart from Windows 10 as said by karthik. Do you have any other idea to approach this?